# Custom layer misses input on plot_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#handling_losses_and_metrics_that_dont_fit_the_standard_signature.

The code in concern is this: (copied from the tutorial)

```py
class LogisticEndpoint(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(LogisticEndpoint, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        self.accuracy_fn = keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

    def call(self, targets, logits, sample_weights=None):
        # Compute the training-time loss value and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_loss()`.
        loss = self.loss_fn(targets, logits, sample_weights)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # Log accuracy as a metric and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_metric()`.
        acc = self.accuracy_fn(targets, logits, sample_weights)
        self.add_metric(acc, name="accuracy")

        # Return the inference-time prediction tensor (for `.predict()`).
        return tf.nn.softmax(logits)


import numpy as np

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(3,), name="inputs")
targets = keras.Input(shape=(10,), name="targets")
logits = keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)

predictions = LogisticEndpoint(name="predictions")(logits, targets)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer="adam")  # No loss argument!
```

What I need is to plot the model, so I called

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'm.png', show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Apprently from the tutorial code LogisticEndpoint takes two input, namely the return value of dense and targets. However in the plot, a link from `target:InputLayer` to `predictions:LogisticEndpoint` is missing.

How would I revise the tutorial code so that plot is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs to your custom layer should be a list/tuple for two input tensors and not two separate inputs. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#call) for more information. You could try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class LogisticEndpoint(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(LogisticEndpoint, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        self.accuracy_fn = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

    def call(self, inputs, sample_weights=None):
        # Compute the training-time loss value and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_loss()`.
        logits, targets = inputs
        loss = self.loss_fn(targets, logits, sample_weights)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # Log accuracy as a metric and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_metric()`.
        acc = self.accuracy_fn(targets, logits, sample_weights)
        self.add_metric(acc, name="accuracy")

        # Return the inference-time prediction tensor (for `.predict()`).
        return tf.nn.softmax(logits)


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,), name="inputs")
targets = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,), name="targets")
logits =tf. keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)

predictions = LogisticEndpoint(name="predictions")([logits, targets])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer="adam")  # No loss argument!

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'm.png', show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This also makes the signature of LogisticEndpoint.call agree with the super class. Thanks!